# How to make changes on final classes?

Tags: java

A company uses a third party library "WoodenTableFactory". It contains 2 **final** classes, `TableMaker` and `TableWorkshop`, and one interface, `In_TableMaker`, which has only one method, `makeTable()`.

At the moment, tables are made with the code below but some customers want their name carved on them.

```
In_TableMaker tableMaker = new TableMaker();
TableWorkshop workshop = new TableWorkshop();
workshop.makeAndDeliverTable (tableMaker);
```

Since they are final classes, they cannot be used as inheritance. Since we cannot change the library, only the code above, how can we solve the problem?

Comment: Use composition.

Comment: @khelwood it's the In_TableMaker, since the other two are instantiated.

Comment: As Fureeish suggested you could use composition and delegation, i.e. have a class `CustomTableMaker implements In_TableMaker` which internally uses an instance of `TableMaker` and in `makeTable()` you add the carving code around the call to `TableMaker.makeTable()`.

Answer (score 4):

The reasonable approach would be to implement your own class that `implements In_TableMake`.

In order to "minimize" your efforts, you probably use *composition* instead of inheritance. In other words, your class implementing that interface might have a **field** of type `TableMaker` that it uses to get its job done internally.

Also note: **inheritance** shouldn't be seen a mean to avoid code duplication. It should be seen from the **typing** perspective. You use to *model* objects/classes in order to come up with a sound design that reflects the problem you intend to solve!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new class that implements the interface `In_TableMaker`.
This class would have the necessary data, and the customized `makeTable()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody has pointed it already, you should use composition. Here is an example:

```
public class MyTableMaker implements In_TableMaker {

   protected TableMaker delegate = new TableMaker();

   // TableMaker methods
   public Object makeTable(Object input) {
       return delegate.method1(input);
   }

   // New methods
   public Object myNewMethod(Object input) {

   }

}
```

You will need to fill the rest of the methods, you could do this automatically with your IDE, for example with Eclipse you could do that pressing CTRL+Shift+S and choosing "Generate delegate methods..."

Answer (score 0):

Use a Wrapper class.

```
class TableMakerExtended implements In_TableMaker {
privete final In_TableMaker tableMaker;

public TableMakerExtended(In_TableMaker tableMaker){
    this.tableMaker = tableMaker;
}

@override
public void makeTable(){
    //....
    tableMaker.makeTable();
    //.....
}
```

}

```
In_TableMaker tableMaker = new TableMaker(); In_TableMaker
tableMakerExtended = new TableMakerExtended (tableMaker );
TableWorkshop workshop = new TableWorkshop();
workshop.makeAndDelivertable (tableMakerExtended );
```